# How to reduce software that is running during idle desktop state, and not needed otherwise?

Tags: configuration, cleanup, maintenance

I see lots of stuff running on my PC that I do not really need. Is there a somewhat **systematic way to reduce** that?

The priority is on geting rid of software that is **actually active**, or **sometimes active**, without producing relevant results.

But even software that is present as processes sleepin almost always, using only trivial amounts of ressources **increases the total complexity** of a computer system a lot, so I like to get rid of that with almost the same priority.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Most processes running are just waiting for something to happen --- keystrokes, mouse movement, devices waking up, network data. So it depends on what you need. No dynamic shared printers? Maybe you can get rid of `avahi` (I do). YMMV....

Comment: @Rmano The question is not more specific - it's abount getting rid of software I do not know. But only the part of it I do not need.

Comment: ...but you can't know if you need it or not if you don't know what it's doing. So the correct question is, IMHO, asking "what's this process doing" for every  process/software running in *your* system (which will be different from the ones running in *my* system) that you don't know what is doing and then decide by yourself if you need it or not. "Sometimes useful" is really personal --- and how am I supposed to know what you don't need?

Answer (score 0):

To see current running processes enter `ps u U <username>` into the terminal.

It will bring up a list of running processes and their status. Note the process ID (**PID**)

To kill a particular process use the command `kill -s signal pid` where *pid* is the PID of the process you want to kill.

*signal* can either be a number or a name:

- `1` or `SIGHUP` - terminates interactive programs and causes daemons to reread their configuration files.
- `9` or `SIGKILL` - causes the process to exit without performing routine shutdown tasks
- `15` or `SIGTERM` - causes processes to exit but allows it to close or open files, etc

In your case you should use `15` or `SIGTERM` as the *signal*.

An example case `kill -s 2496 SIGTERM`